# Sybase ASE: Add NOT NULL column without a DEFAULT fails. Why?

Tags: sql, sybase, default-value, sap-ase

Consider the following empty (as in without rows) table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    my_column CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Trying to add a NOT NULL column without a DEFAULT will fail:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_new_column CHAR(10) NOT NULL;

Error:

*[Code: 4997, SQL State: S1000]
ALTER TABLE my_table failed. 
Default clause is required in order to add non-NULL column 'my_new_column'.
```

But adding the column as NULL and then change it to be NOT NULL will work:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_new_column CHAR(10) NULL;
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY my_new_column CHAR(10) NOT NULL;
```

Setting a default and then removing the default will work too:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD my_new_column CHAR(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE my_table REPLACE my_new_column DEFAULT NULL;
```

What's the justification for this behavior? What is the database trying to do internally that adding the column directly fails? I have a feeling that it might have something to do with internal versioning but I can't find anything in this regard.

Comment: I recommend you run your tests again but this time with some data in the table; get back to us with which commands succeed vs fail ... that should give you a bit more insight as to what's happening (eg, is the command merely modifying the schema? is the command creating a new table and copying data from the old table? are the error messages generated during the parse/compile phase? are the error messages generated during the execution phase?)

Comment: It's well established and obvious why you can't add a NOT NULL column without a DEFAULT to a table that already has rows and it's because the engine needs a value to populate the previously existing rows for the new column. My question pertains the why this happens to a table that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is only speculation, but I suspect it has to do the combination of needing to *both* acquire a lock on the whole table to guarantee continued compliance with the schema, *and* re-allocate space for the records.

Allowing a direct add of a `NOT NULL` column would compromise any existing records if there's no default value. Yes, **we** know the table is empty. And the database can (eventually) know the table is empty at *execution time*... but it can't really know the table is empty at execution plan compile time, because a row could be added while the execution plan is determined.

This means the database would need to generate the worst-possible execution plan, involving a lock on the entire table, for the query to run in a transactionally-safe way. Additionally, adding (or removing) a column causes extra work for the database because it needs to re-allocate any pages and rebuild indexes in order to account for the changed size of individual records.

Put the two together, and it becomes difficult to just rollback a failed query, because you may have actual pages in different states. For whatever reason, the developers chose not to allow this.

The other options allow you to simply fail the query if a bad row gets in the way and would violate the schema, because you're not re-sizing records within pages. It might even allow you to get away with some page and row locks, rather than full table locks.

Comment: This answer is very different from the original. If you read it earlier, you may want to read it again. It makes more sense now.

Comment: Wouldn't this also impact the ALTER TABLE to remove the NULL restriction from the column? Because that works as expected, it's just the ADDITION of a NOT NULL column that fails.

Comment: No, because removing the restriction doesn't change the size of the data.. The database can just do a normal error the query with a normal rollback. Even removing the entire column, which would change the size of the data, could be okay because there's no risk for bad data violating the schema.

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation.  I am guessing that Sybase is being overly conservative.  In general, you cannot add a new `not null` column with no `default` value to a table *that has rows*.  This is true in all databases, because there is no way to populate the existing rows for the new column.

I am guessing that Sybase simply doesn't check if the table has rows, only if it exists.  Clearly it is not doing the check for the `alter`.

Comment: This does not explain why you CAN add the field first as NOT NULL and then use ALTER TABLE again right after that to set the field as NULL. It's still ALTER TABLE and everything else is the same.

Comment: @JosephSabido . . . One branch of the code checks if the table exists.  The other checks if the table has rows.  You are correct that they are inconsistent.